# Google Maps aPI v3 based map not responding to mouse events in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a map using the Google Maps API.  Works great in every browser except for IE, where, the map does not respond to the mouse - no cursor change, no mouse wheel zoom, no click events at all.  No errors are raised via the console in the IE developer tools.  I'm not sure where to begin looking other than commenting out sections of code until I figure out the offending section.  Has anyone else every experienced this?

Sample Map (open in IE to observe the behavior)

http://notinmyneighbourhood.com/mapTest.php

Thanks in advance!

I'm pretty sure it is related to CSS as this CSSless (is that a new word?) version works fine:

http://notinmyneighbourhood.com/mapTest2.php

Comment: Can you provide a link to the problem map (or a jsfiddle that exhibits the behavior)?

Comment: Most definitely...http://notinmyneighbourhood.com/mapTest.php

Comment: Think you need to change the tags on this question.  It doesn't seem to have anything to do with Google Maps or the Google Maps API v3.

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing with?

Comment: IE 9 - haven't tried IE8 or IE7 yet...

Answer (score 0):

In IE your mask is over top of the map, blocking all the clicks.

Comment: Yuck...known issue in IE...guess IE users will have to have the plain version of the map! http://caniuse.com/pointer-events